# SPARQL filter and union

Tags: filter, sparql

I am trying to list all entries whose names start with the letter 'R' and are older than 20 but It is not working - Can you please give me a hint ?

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?givenname ?Age ?firstName
WHERE {
    ?Person foaf:givenname ?firstName
    {FILTER (?Age > '20')}
    UNION
    {FILTER regex(?givename, "^(R)")}
}
```

Comment: "not working" is not a meaningful error description ... it comprises, parse errors, empty results etc .

Comment: also, without seeing proper sample data it's always a mess to help.

Comment: for your current query, you're filtering by Age, but where did you bind the age to a variable? Also, is the age an integer value or a string as you wrote '20' which denotes the string "20" but not the number 20

Comment: Also, what's the idea behind putting the FILTER clauses into a UNION? The union is basically for BGPs, i.e. graph patterns. Both filters currently apply to nothing in that case. If you want to have a disjunction on filter expressions, do `FILTER(expr1 || expr2)` for intersection use `&&`

Answer (score 0):

To find names that start with "R", you can use [`STRSTARTS()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts):

```
FILTER( STRSTARTS(?givename, "R") ) .
```

To filter based on the age, you first have to add/bind this variable in a triple pattern, e.g.:

```
?Person ex:yourAgeProperty ?Age .
```

Your age `FILTER` compares strings (as you use quotation marks and don’t specify a datatype, which defaults to `xsd:string`). In case the age is given as `xsd:integer` in your data, you could use:

```
FILTER( ?Age > "20"^^xsd:integer ) .
```

And if both filters need to apply, simply list them one after the other (without `{}` and without `UNION`). Or you could combine them:

```
FILTER( STRSTARTS(?givename, "R") && ?Age > "20"^^xsd:integer ) .
```